# How to format filepath to raw string so that there isn't an error in unzipping

Tags: python, unzip, shutil, rawstring

I am trying to extract only the .tsv files in sub-directories in a zip file. I keep getting an error because the file paths look like this

**'C:\Users\hcho\OneDrive - Biocept\Schultz\Unzip\variant_oncomine_tsv_2020-02-25\SCRS_02JAN2020_B_v1_Filtered_2020-02-21_10:40:54-oncomine.tsv' with double '\'**

instead of the raw string

**'C:\Users\hcho\OneDrive - Biocept\Schultz\Unzip\variant_oncomine_tsv_2020-02-25\SCRS_02JAN2020_B_v1_Filtered_2020-02-21_10:40:54-oncomine.tsv'**

How do I convert the output of os.getcwd() so that it comes out as a literal string?

Here is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import glob
import zipfile
import io
from datetime import date
import shutil

zip_files = []
for file in glob.glob("*.zip"):
    zip_files.append(file)

today = str(date.today())
new_dir_name = 'variant_oncomine_tsv'+'_'+today
if new_dir_name not in os.listdir():
    os.mkdir(new_dir_name)
cur_dir = os.getcwd()
destin = cur_dir+'\\'+new_dir_name
destin2 = r'variant_oncomine_tsv_2020-02-25'
def extract_oncomine_tsv(filename):
    with zipfile.ZipFile(filename) as z:
        for f in z.namelist():
            if '-oncomine.tsv' in f:
                filename = os.path.basename(f)
                #skip directories:
                if not filename:
                    continue

                #copy file (taken from zipfile's extract)
                source = z.open(f)
                target = open(os.path.join(destin,filename),'wb')
                with source, target:
                    shutil.copyfileobj(source, target)

for zips in zip_files:
    e = extract_oncomine_tsv(zips)
```

This is the error message I get:

[image]

Comment: You don't "convert to raw string", it is only an *input* convention. That error message is just following standard `print` escaping – there are no double backslashes in there. Your error lies elsewhere.

Comment: Please remove space between the file path, for example: `OneDrive - Biocept\` have space between two words.

Comment: @Ratnesh just tested in another directory without spaces, this still doesn't work.